# Unable to find the sql server provider as data source

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, datasource

trying to follow this tutorial http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/net30/article.php/c15489 I'm not able to select the sql server provider as data source.
I've only file and sql compact.

I've installed sql server 2008 express and management studio.

What do I miss ?

Thanks in advance for any help

Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that with web developper express, we can access to this data source although with visual c# express, we can't